# Django Query to get how many times how many emails are repeated

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm using a Customer model

```
    class Customer(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        email = models.EmailField()

For eg: table has following data:
    id Email 
    101  a@abc.com
    102  b@abc.com
    103  c@abc.com
    104  a@abc.com
    105  b@abs.com
    106  b@abc.com
    107  d@abc.com
    108  d@abc.com

I want following Output:

    number of times  number of emails
    1     1  (c@abc.com)
    2     2  (d@abc.com, a@abc.com)
    3     1  (b@abc.com)
```

I want a query to get the how many times the email repeated:

I tried following query 
Customer.objects.all().values('email').annotate(total=Count('email')).order_by('total')
Which gives the following output

```
   [  
       {  
          'total':1,
          'email':u'cgaujjlitU@example.com'
       },
       {  
          'total':1,
          'email':u'fgh@dfg.com'
       },
       {  
          'total':1,
          'email':u'jay@dfg.com'
       },
       {  
          'total':1,
          'email':u'test3@gmail.com'
       },

       {  
          'total':1,
          'email':u'tester19@fgh.com'
       },
       {  
          'total':2,
          'email':u'carlos+bj1@fgh.io'
       },

       {  
          'total':17,
          'email':u'dfe@sedd.com'
       }
    ]
```

Comment: So you want to further aggregate them? like the email-adresses fgh@dfg.com and jay@dfg.com only occured 1 time?

Comment: Yes @MaximilianKindshofer

Answer (score 3):

```
aggregated_list = Customer.objects.all().values('email').annotate(total=Count('email')).order_by('total') 

email_occurance = {}
for item in aggregated_list:
    get_total = item['total']
    if get_total not in email_occurance:
       email_occurance[get_total] = (item['email'],)
    else:
       existing_email_tuple = email_occurance[get_total]
       existing_email_list = list(existing_email_tuple)
       existing_email_list.append(item['email'])
       new_email_tuple = tuple(existing_email_list)
       email_occurance[get_total] = new_email_tuple
```

will give you:

```
email_occurance= {
    1: ('cgaujjlitU@example.com', 
        'fgh@dfg.com', 
        'jay@dfg.com', 
        'test3@gmail.com', 
        'tester19@fgh.com'
        ), 
    2: ('carlos+bj1@fgh.io',), 
    17: ('dfe@sedd.com',)
    }
```

Is this the output you need?

Answer (score 2):

You need to step into the world of raw sql but not all databases support it. With postgresql you need to look at  [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) while in mysql and sqlite the function to use is  [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)